# What's the best way to execute a code block based on the input of a user if it matches a value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I've tried two ways to achieve this, please see below:

```
var cat = ['travel', 'business', 'environment', 'culture', 'football', 'politics', 'world', 'commentisfree', 'lifestyle', 'fashion', 'technology', 'sport', 'money', 'science'];

var userInput = $("#mySearch").val();

for(var i=0; i < cat.length; i++){
    if (userInput == cat[i]){
        // do something
    }else{
        // do something else
    }
}
```

This worked, however the else condition was executed until it found the value. I then tried to lose the array with the below:

```
var userInput = $("#mySearch").val();

if ( userInput == 'travel' || 'business' || 'environment' || 'culture' || 'football' || 'politics' || 'world' || 'commentisfree' || 'lifestyle' || 'fashion' || 'technology' || 'sport' || 'money' || 'science' ){
    // do something
}else{
    // do something else
}
```

This way also works, however, it fires for values that aren't between the condition brackets (not entirely sure why??). Explanations and solutions are more than welcome! I'm new to JS

Comment: try [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: well think about it, you can not run it in the else since it needs to check on every iteration if there is a match. You do not know if there is not a match until you have gone over all the values. So what does that mean? You would only run it after the loop is over and it has not found anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery, you can use the following:

```
if ($.inArray(userInput, cat) > -1) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you wanted to use vanilla JS, you could use `indexOf`. You can read more about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: No worries :) The documentation for `inArray` is here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ - the function returns -1 if the value cannot be found in the array. If it can be found in the array, the function will return the index of where it found the value. If you feel this has helped you out, please remember to mark as correct answer/upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use indexOf it will return the index of the occurrence if value found in array else -1

```
 var cat = ['travel', 'business', 'environment', 'culture', 'football', 'politics', 'world', 'commentisfree', 'lifestyle', 'fashion', 'technology', 'sport', 'money', 'science'];

 var userInput = $("#mySearch").val();

 if(cat.indexOf(userInput) !== -1){
   //present
 }else{
   //absent
 }
```

Comment: thank you for this, may i ask what the "**-1**" does in this?

Comment: @Chima If the elements exists in array it will return the index of that element inside array possibly 0 to length-1 , but if element does not exist it return -1 hence -1 can be used as indication that element does not exists

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one; I'll start with your second part, where we have

```js
if ( userInput == 'travel' || 'business' || 'environment' || 'culture' || 'football' || 'politics' || 'world' || 'commentisfree' || 'lifestyle' || 'fashion' || 'technology' || 'sport' || 'money' || 'science' ){
    // do something
}
```

The reason the first part evaluates to true is that it's testing the 'truthy-ness" of 'business', which is true; strings in javascript are true. To make it work as intended, you'd have to add userInput === 'business'

I think with your first if/else statement, you could just take out the else. This would prevent anything from executing unless the if condition was met.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't require JQuery:

```
var cat = ['travel', 'business', 'environment', 'culture', 'football', 'politics', 'world', 'commentisfree', 'lifestyle', 'fashion', 'technology', 'sport', 'money', 'science'];

var userInput = $("#mySearch").val();

// Check to see if the user input is in the array.
if(cat.indexOf(userInput) !== -1) {
  // Input matches an array item lets do some stuff.
}
```

The "indexOf" function will return the index in the array of the matching item or "-1" if there is no matching items.

Answer (score 0):

I would just filter out the undesirable values with `.filter` and then execute your desired code. This way, you avoid the situation where userInput could be a value that is not within your range, and only execute code when a valid input is present.

```
var cat = [vals...];
var userInput = $("#mySearch").val();

const inCategories = (item, i, arr) => {
    return arr.indexOf(userInput) !== -1; };
};

if (cat.filter(inCategories).length > 0){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the built-in **some()** to check if an input is an element of an array

```js
var cat = ['travel', 'business', 'environment', 'culture', 'football', 'politics', 'world', 'commentisfree', 'lifestyle', 'fashion', 'technology', 'sport', 'money', 'science'];
var input = 'world';
if (cat.some(x => x === input)) console.log(input + " is a category");
else console.log(input + " is not a category");
```